# QtApplication Error. Sound Effect is not a type. M300 error

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt6

I am facing a QQmlApplicationEngine failure while loading a component. The error is mentioned below:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/KBButton.qml:54:5: SoundEffect is not a type
```

The following section of KBButton.qml is failing:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Rectangle {
    id: kbButton
    property double size: 100
    x: centerX - width / 2
    y: centerY - height / 2

    SoundEffect { ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Error occurs here. Unknown Component (M300)
        id: clickSound
        source: "resources/ClickSound.wav"
    }

    onClick: {
        isSelected = false;
        expManager.logKeyClicked(objectName)
        clickSound.play();
    }
}
```

**.pro file** contains the following. Although I am importing QtMultimedia in qml files and not in C++ files, I still added the multimedia and multimediawidgets to qmake project file

`QT += qml quick widgets core quickcontrols2 multimedia multimediawidgets`

The code model could be reset using the Main Menu option available in QtCreator, as suggested by some online forums:

`Tools > QML/JS > Reset Code Model`
but this did not work. It didn't help either to run qmake again.

What can be done to resolve this error?

Comment: Please avoid posting your code as an image, just provide [mcve] so we can test it.

Comment: Which Qt version you are using?

Comment: @Aamir I am using Qt 6.3.1 on macOS.

Comment: @folibis I have updated the question. Thank you for redirecting me to the Help Center link.

Comment: Not sure, but try with `import QtMultimedia` instead of `import QtMultimedia 5.15`. Check also in your Qt installation (via Qt Maintenance Tool) that you have the right modules for your version.

Comment: Thank you, Tarod! Removing the version helped.

Comment: Ok, great! I added the answer below so please upvote me if you are happy with the solution.

Comment: I accepted the solution, Tarod! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, QML should load the right version for you, so in this case it seems a good solution is to remove the version from your `import`: `import QtMultimedia` instead of `import QtMultimedia 5.15`

More info about the import statement: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-imports.html